# Rules of thumb for using IEEE 754 floating pointer numbers?

Tags: floating-point

Software engineers are generally directed to the article '[What Every Computer Scientist Must Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)' when they want to know more about floating point arithmetic. However, this article is too long and requires a lot of effort to extract the gist of the article. So I was wondering if there are any 'rules of thumb' that one can remember while doing floating-point arithmetic so as to minimize floating point error?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few guidelines.   However, they are a poor substitute for effort to properly understand, and to analyse properties of your algorithms.   You are really better off applying effort to learn enough of the basics so you can understand that article.

Some of the guidelines on individual operations include;

- Avoid subtracting values of approximately equal value (or adding values of opposite sign but roughly equal magnitude)
- Avoid addition of values of very different sizes
- Avoid testing two floating point values for equality, if either is
  the result of a series of numeric operations

The most important guideline, however, is to prefer using a good quality numeric library wherever possible, rather than rolling too much of your own code that uses floating point.  This is simply because such libraries have been designed by experts - i.e. people who understand the things you don't want to think about - to achieve good numeric properties (stability, etc).

If you really must roll your own code, take the time to find good algorithms.    Even if your understanding and coding practice are less than ideal, a good algorithm offers benefits.

Comment: That article is by Goldberg.  What's fun about your first guideline is that the difference of two floating-point numbers of roughly equal magnitude incurs *no* roundoff at all (Sterbenz's theorem); if the values themselves are the result of arithmetic that rounded, it simply makes plain the problem that occurred earlier.

Comment: It's not my guideline.   It is, however, one that is often quoted.   The problem it addresses is not round-off in the subtraction.   The reason I've seen cited is that it is that the results of such operations - in practice - are often used as the denominator in a division - and therefore magnify errors in the numerator.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and that's often how you think about things in practice.  But the case where both arguments to the subtraction are exact floating-point numbers arises fairly often, either directly or because of a "change of philosophy" in an algorithm.

Comment: You should really change the mention of Knuth in your answer, unless you mean to refer to an article written by Knuth, in which case I am sorry to report that it is not clear which.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Which guideline is not obeyed when using Heron's formula for the area of a triangle [S=(a+b+c)/2; area=sqrt(S(S-A)(S-B)(S-C))] with sides 16777215.0f, 16777215.0f, and 4.0f?  It seems to be that the subtraction of values of near-equal magnitude is what turns an error of less than 0.2 parts per million into an error of 500,000ppm (and nary a division in sight!)

Comment: @supercat: You compute S = 16777216.0f there where you wanted S = 16777217.0.  (Or you get S = 16777218.0f if you add it as a+(b+c); same difference.)  The subtractions S-A and S-B result in the totally wrong value 1.0f.  However, this error was not introduced by the subtraction; it was already there when you computed S.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Rounding errors are in many cases inevitable when working with floating-point values; some algorithms tend cause rounding errors to yield comparable errors in the result, but subtraction of near-equal numbers will magnify the effects of rounding errors.  Subtracting numbers of near-equal magnitude is bad except when both values are likely to be "perfect".  Personally, I regret that ANSI C failed so badly to support IEEE-754's intended computation model, since computations of the form (a+b+c) would often yield *much* better results than under today's common model...

Comment: ...and only occasionally yield very slightly less precise results.  For some special-purpose computations, doing everything in one type makes sense, but in most cases having an extended-precision intermediate result type *which is available to the programmer* makes things much cleaner.  Given today's floating-point paradigm, it's important to ensure that floating-point values are acted upon in the right sequence, since failure to do so can yield results with hardly any precision.

Comment: So does that mean there's no other substitute other than to read the complete document?

Comment: It does mean that rules of thumb are no substitute for reading and understanding relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those made by Peter, I would suggest that you try to understand if and when your language makes use of intermediate precision: typically this arises due to the use of 80-bit floating point numbers at the hardware level, and different behaviour may arise depending on when it rounds the result to the target precision (32-bit or 64-bit).

This is usually not a problem in interpreted languages (e.g. Python, JavaScript), but for compiled languages, issues relating to this arise quite frequently on this site (and is perhaps the key reason behind the folk wisdom for avoiding comparison of floating point numbers).

In particular:

- In C/C++, make sure you understand understand the different [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) behaviours, and that this value will depend on the choice of compiler, compiler options and architecture.
- C# has similar behaviour: this is controlled by the [`/fp` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx).
- Java is not quite so problematic (from what I understand, I have limited Java experience): `double`s will only use 64-bit precision, but may use an extended exponent range: the net effect is that some computations will give a numeric result when they would otherwise underflow or overflow. This can be disabled with the [`FP-strict` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4).